# Сортировка обьекта в котором обьекты. По строкам и цифрам

Tags: javascript, объекты

Подскажите как отсортировать обьект в котором другие обьекты по строкам и цифрам?
Сортировка массива объектов по строкам осуществляется просто:

```js
var test = [
  { name: "Бананы", price: 2000 },
  { name: "Сливы", price: 1000 },
  { name: "Тыква", price: 1200 },
  { name: "Ананасы", price: 3000  }
];
test.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
  if (obj1.name < obj2.name) return -1;
  if (obj1.name > obj2.name) return 1;
  return 0;
});
console.log(test);
```

А нужно что б так примерно было :

```js
var test = {
   '0':{ name: "Бананы", price: 2000 },
   '1':{ name: "Сливы", price: 1000 },
   '2':{ name: "Тыква", price: 1200 },
   '3':{ name: "Ананасы", price: 3000  }
 };
 
 
 
 test.sort(function(obj2, obj1) {
   if (obj1.name < obj2.name) return -1;
   if (obj1.name > obj2.name) return 1;
   return 0;
 });
console.log(test);
```

Нужно что б бананы и сливы отсортировались по алфавиту =)

Comment: _объект_ **нельзя** сортировать. Кроме этого непонятно что делается во втором примере и какой должен быть результат в итоге

Comment: @Grundy, предположительно, требуется сортировка, только не массив объектов, а объект объектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var test = {
  '0': {
    name: "Бананы",
    price: 2000
  },
  '1': {
    name: "Сливы",
    price: 1000
  },
  '2': {
    name: "Тыква",
    price: 1200
  },
  '3': {
    name: "Ананасы",
    price: 3000
  }
}, tmp = [];

// Преобразование в массив

// ES2017 (сейчас работает в Chrome && FF)
tmp = Object.values(test);

// Старый, добрый цикл
for(let key in test)
  if(test.hasOwnProperty(key))
    tmp.push(test[key]);


// Сортируем
tmp = tmp.sort(function(obj2, obj1) {
  if(obj1.name < obj2.name) return 1;
  if(obj1.name > obj2.name) return -1;
  return 0;
});
console.info(tmp);
```

Comment: `sort` меняет исходный массив. нет нужды присваивать его самому себе. Ну и на выходе - массив, а не объект, и неизвестно что нужно было автору

Comment: @Grundy, верно, пожалуй, но ключи всё равно цифровые.

Comment: а у вас тут ошибка не выпадает ""message": "Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function","  ?

Comment: @user3319778, это и есть признак старого браузера. Можете убрать строку `tmp = Object.values(test);`, она для демонстрации только.

Comment: точно, щас всё работает хорошо. Спасибо это то что нужно !